# Call to undefined method App\Models\User::hasRole() with a middleware Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to use a middleware to validate the roles and I'm using the example that is in Laravel documentation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EnsureUserHasRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
            return back();
        }
        return $next($request);


    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error of the question. This is how I have written the Route.

`Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos')->middleware('auth','firstLogin','role:administrador');`

The middleware is called role and I plan to use it to only allow access the supported roles for it.

It surprises me it doesn't work because I'm using the example in Laravel documentation.

The User model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'role',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'idPersona',
        'estado'
    ];
    
    public function Persona(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class,'idPersona');
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Roles are not a Laravel feature; could you link the documentation you are following that shows a user model called with a `hasRole` function? It sounds more like you have installed a library but not correctly set it up. Are you maybe missing a trait on the user model? Maybe Spatie permission package? And you forgot to add `use HasRoles;` to the User Model?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware Im using the example in middleware with parameters, I'm new in Laravel and I thought that function came by default. I think I made my User model with a migration not really sure but I customed it. I can place the User Model code in the question. @NicklasKevinFrank

Comment: Your user model doesn't have a `HasRole` function so you cannot call `$request->user()->hasRole($role)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `EnsureUserHasRole` to your middleware array

```
Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos')->middleware('auth','firstLogin','EnsureUserHasRole', 'role:administrador');
```

Comment: I called role the middleware in the kernel file so I think its ok the way I have it. The comments above were right, I missed the method